# Is there a way to dinamically perform this loop?

Tags: python

do you know how if there is a better way to perform this task without using for loop?

Starting with the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [90, 85, 85, 85, 100, 170, 150, 130, 125, 125], 
'B':[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]})
df['C'] = 0
df.loc[0, 'C'] = df.loc[0, 'B']
df['D'] = 0
df.loc[0, 'D'] = df.loc[0, 'C'] * 0.95
df['E'] = 0
df.loc[0, 'E'] = df.loc[0, 'C'] * 0.80
```

Now,
if the value in **row 1 column A** is greater than the value in **row 0 column D**:

- the value in row 1 column C will be equal to the value in row 1 column A * 2
- the value in row 1 column D will be equal to the value in row 1 column C * 0.95
- the value in row 1 column E will be equal to the value in row 1 column D * 0.8

elif the value in **row 1 column A** is less than the value in **row 0 column E**:

- the value in row 1 column C will be equal to the value in row 1 column A
- the value in row 1 column D will be equal to the value in row 1 column C * 0.95
- the value in row 1 column E will be equal to the value in row 1 column D * 0.8

else:

- the value in **row 1 column C** will be equal to the value in **row 0 column C**
- the value in row 1 column D will be equal to the value in row 1 column C * 0.95
- the value in row 1 column E will be equal to the value in row 1 column D * 0.8

As output, I would like to create a df like this:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'A': [90, 85, 85, 85, 100, 170, 150, 130, 125, 125], 
'B':[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
'C':[100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 150, 150, 150, 150],
'D':[95, 95, 95, 95, 190, 190, 190, 143, 143, 143],
'E':[80, 80, 80, 80, 160, 160, 160, 120, 120, 120]})
```

Considering that I have to iterate for more than 5000 rows and for around 3000 possible scenarios I'm looking for the fastest way to perform this task and I've noted that the for loop is extremely slow.

Thank you guys in advance and apologize for the trivial question!! I'm new to python and I'm trying to learn as much as possible!!

Best

Comment: Are you sure your `df_out` is correct? Row 4 has A=100 and C=200, which seems to not fit your rules. Also, column `B` doesn't seem relevant; if so, you should remove it from the question to simplify what you're asking. You also appear to be rounding off numbers to integers, so you should indicate how and when you do that. As for whether or not to do this as a loop, how "slow" is too slow? A loop to do this 3000x for a random "A" column that was 5000 elements long took about 15 seconds or so.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the comment, the loop takes about 12 seconds for each iteration and I have to perform around 4000 iterations, so 4000 * 12 seconds the total time needed to perform the task and it seems a huge amout of time to me! Anyway there was an error in the first "if" where the multiplier is equal to 2 instead of 1.5 and yes the column B is not relevant so I can drop. With regard to rounding, I have to round the column C D E to the first integer.

Comment: I think your loop is doing something inefficient, because if I'm interpreting it correctly, the version of the loop I made (which does the work in Python lists and then makes a dataframe at the end) takes about 5 millseconds to handle an 'A" list 5000 element long. It doesn't directly answer your question, but it might solve your problem, so I can post that as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments, if you do the loop this way it's reasonably quick:

```
alist = [90, 85, 85, 85, 100, 170, 150, 130, 125, 125] * 500

a = alist[0]
c = 100
d = 95
e = 80
clist = [c]
dlist = [d]
elist = [e]
for a in alist[1:]:
    if a > d:
        c_new = round(a*1.5)
    elif a < e:
        c_new = a
    else:
        c_new = c
    c = c_new
    d = round(c_new * 0.95)
    e = round(d * 0.8)
    clist.append(c_new)
    dlist.append(d)
    elist.append(e)

df_out = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : alist, 'C' : clist, 'D' : dlist, 'E' : elist })

print(df_out.head(10))
     A    C    D    E
0   90  100   95   80
1   85  100   95   76
2   85  100   95   76
3   85  100   95   76
4  100  150  142  114
5  170  255  242  194
6  150  150  142  114
7  130  150  142  114
8  125  150  142  114
9  125  150  142  114
```

Comment: yea, transforming into a list is for sure more efficient! The time needed is more than halved and should be ok for that I have to do. Thank you Rick for your help!!!

Comment: You're welcome! If you have a moment, please mark the answer as "accepted" above.